# jQuery expand/collapse TR in table with click

Tags: jquery

I have a table which generated from a database and i cannot change the code behind. Basically is it just a really long list of events separated by day. I would like to set up the table so you can click on the date and then display the events for that day. As I say the only change the html. It's an xsl file generating the page and it is just a long output loop generating a table. I want to hide the Event rows under the Day row and be able to click by Day to show the events. This would be easy if I could change the class of each day but I can't as the data is generated and I cant change the programming.

```html
<table>
<tr class="Date"><td>Day 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Event 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Event 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Event 3</td></tr>

<tr class="Date"><td>Day 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Event 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Event 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Event 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Event 4</td></tr>

<tr class="Date"><td>Day 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Event 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Event 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) is an answer for your question:

> **nextUntil(selector)** - Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed

```
$('.Date').click( function() {
   $(this).nextUntil('.Date').toggleClass('hide'); // don't use toggle() because it change display to block/none, we have to use display table-row
}).click(); // hide by default
```

And css:

```
tr.hide { display: none; }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrqqjubL/)

Comment: Thanks, this works great for the example I gave but the real table is huge and there are other tables on the page. It's not working in my application for some reason. I will try and dig into it. Thanks.

Comment: Just use more precise selectors - set table id for example.